# GNU as .macro placeholder immediately followed by character

Tags: assembly, gnu

In the GNU assembler, I defined a macro like this.

```
.macro test_cond condition, index
    STR\conditionB r4, [r6, #\index*17]
.endm

test_cond EQ, 0
```

It is supposed to expand to

```
STREQB r4, [r6, #0*17]
```

Instead it fails with

```
bad instruction `streq\conditionB r4,[r6,#0*17]'
```

Is there a way to have a placeholder in a macro the be immediately followed by a character?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `\()`construct to separate the macro argument from the character that follows it:

```
.macro test_cond condition, index
    STR\condition\()B r4, [r6, #\index*17]
.endm
```